# Websocket not connecting to openfire using firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket, xmpp, openfire

I have the following script through which I am trying to connect to openfire using WebSocket built in Firefox.

**index.js**

```
console.log(window.WebSocket);
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5222/")
```

but it shows me the following error on browser console.

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at
>   ws://localhost:5222/.

can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong or there any other better way of doing this. I am using the latest version of Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure you have installed Openfire **WebSocket plugin** in the Openfire. so first check it's availability in plugins available. and then write the code as follows.

```
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:7070/ws/",'xmpp')
```

XMPP is the protocol for openfire

in case you want to check for the error you have to do like this.

```
exampleSocket.onerror = function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Please note that the functionality provided by this plugin is added to Openfire direclty in version 4.2.0. This plugin is no longer needed in Openfire 4.2.0 or later!